# How do you checkout a branch in a child repository in gitslave?

Tags: git, git-slave

I have a super repository with several child repositories.  I want to change one of the child repositories to another branch.  But, when I use `git checkout` to do it, after a `gits status` the child repo is somehow back on the master branch.  What is the proper way to change branches on a child repository?

Comment: use submodules - https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

Comment: @Aky_0788 I switched to submodules and it's much better.

Comment: glad it helps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I just tried with the latest version of gitslave patched to support the git status update change (gits version 2.0.2-42-dirty), and gitslave does NOT change what branch you are on. It warns that you are on the wrong branch.

Are you using some alternate version of gitslave that someone updated to be "helpful" in some way?

Generally, gitslave is probably not the right solution if you are going to be on different branches on different repos.  It will work (2.0.2 will) but it will be on the frustrating side.

```
Top-level (top) branch 'master' != slave branch 'test1'!
# On branch master
On: mid:
  Top-level (top) branch 'master' != slave branch 'test1'!
  Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/test1'.

  nothing to commit, working tree clean
On: (top):
  Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

  nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Comment: Your guess is right.  I was using a branch I found on github.  I'm selecting this answer, with the note that submodules work much better for this use case.